# Webpack babel loader outputting full C:/ drive urls in bundles

Tags: webpack, arcgis-js-api, babel-loader

I'm working on building a web mapping app using the arcgis javascript api and the arcgis webpack plugin. The arcgis webpack plugin is essentially the dojo plugin which bundles a dojo loader into the output webpack bundle.

My webpack build has full C:/path/to/files in the output bundles. This is causing problems loading files in production mode. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
const ArcGISPlugin = require('@arcgis/webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'main': './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath: '',
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist', 'build']),
        new ArcGISPlugin({
            useDefaultAssetLoaders: false,
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: './[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: './[id].[hash].css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'none',
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            template: './src/oauth-callback.html',
            filename: './oauth-callback.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'none',
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.stache$/,
            use: [{loader: 'raw-loader'}],
        }, {
            test: /\.layout$/,
            use: [{loader: 'raw-loader'}],
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    sourceMap: true,
                },
            }],
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}, {
                    loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                    options: {includeRoot: true},
                },
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'less-loader',
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}, {
                    loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                    options: {includeRoot: true, sourceMap: true},
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|webp)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                // Inline files smaller than 10 kB (10240 bytes)
                limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
        }, {
            test: /\.(wsv|ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'build/[name].[ext]',
                },
            }],
        }],
    },


    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules/'],
        alias: {
            'esri': 'arcgis-js-api',
            'sweetalert2$': 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2',
            'moment': 'moment/moment',
        },
    },


    node: {
        process: false,
        global: false,
        fs: 'empty',
    },


    externals: [
        (context, request, callback) => {
            if (/pe-wasm$/.test(request)) {
                return callback(null, 'amd ' + request);
            }
            callback();
        },
    ],
};
```

My production webpack config looks like this:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const {BundleAnalyzerPlugin} = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const {DefinePlugin} = require('webpack');
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    plugins: [
        new DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
            },
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'static',
        }),
    ],
})
;
```

I am seeing lots of paths like this in my output bundle:

```
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/components/cia-open-project/cia-open-project": 1667,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/components/cia-open-project/cia-open-project.less": 1668,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/components/cia-open-project/cia-open-project.stache": 1670,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/components/cia-open-project/ViewModel": 1673,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/config/map/view": 1692,
        "esri/Map": 1695,
        "esri/ground/navigationConstraints": 1696,
        "esri/support/groundUtils": 1697,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/styles/main.scss": 1698,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/config/hooks/index": 1703,
        "@wsb/dl-identify-hooks/identify/highlightIdentify": 1704,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/arcgis-js-api/layers/support/layerUtils": 1706,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/arcgis-js-api/tasks/support/IdentifyResult": 1707,
        "C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--6-0!C:/Users/<username>/web/dl2-cia-wsb/src/config/map/layers": 1708
```

Here's my package deps:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --progress --host=lvh.me --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "deploy": "npm run build",
    "postdeploy": "node ./scripts/deploy",
    "license": "webpack --config licenses/webpack.licenses.js",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wsb/dl-app": "^1.0.3",
    "@wsb/dl-auth-oauth": "^2.0.1",
    "@wsb/dl-autocomplete": "^0.1.2",
    "@wsb/dl-draw": "^1.1.4",
    "@wsb/dl-edit": "^1.1.0",
    "@wsb/dl-esri-widget-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "@wsb/dl-feature-table": "^2.0.2",
    "@wsb/dl-filter": "^0.1.0",
    "@wsb/dl-identify-hooks": "^1.0.2",
    "@wsb/dl-login": "^2.0.0",
    "@wsb/dl-map": "^1.0.2",
    "@wsb/dl-pdf-generator": "^1.0.1",
    "@wsb/dl-toolbar": "^1.0.2",
    "@wsb/dl-util": "^1.0.0",
    "arcgis-js-api": "^4.8.1",
    "can-arcgis": "^3.0.0",
    "can-component": "^4.0.8",
    "can-define": "^2.3.1",
    "can-route": "^4.1.1",
    "can-stache": "^4.4.0",
    "can-stache-route-helpers": "<2.0.0",
    "can-util": "^3.12.0",
    "can-view-model": "^4.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.5.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.36",
    "spectre-canjs": "^3.2.0",
    "spectre.css": "^0.5.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.26.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arcgis/webpack-plugin": "^4.8.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.3",
    "can-debug": "^1.2.2",
    "can-stache-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "can-view-import": "^4.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "command-line-args": "^5.0.2",
    "command-line-usage": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "datauri": "^1.1.0",
    "donejs-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "form-data": "^2.3.2",
    "generator-donejs": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-license-crawler": "^0.1.9",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack-strip-block": "^0.2.0",
    "zip-dir": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems specific to the @arcgis/webpack-plugin, I suggest opening an issue over there that links back here: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-webpack-plugin/issues